# Cumsum function in python

Tags: python-2.7

I have the below-mentioned dataset.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/13GCAXHp5BU4vYU6PdX40wM-Jhp--LeRd9C5oUurbVY4/edit#gid=0

I want to find the cumulative values for sales for difference stores in one column. For example, the cumulative value for store 2106 the sales figure should be 176,849

I'm using the following function

df = df.groupby('storenumber')['sales'].cumsum() but i am not getting the correct result

Can someone help?

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I did to solve this problem.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_csv('data.csv') # get data frame from csv file
```

You won't be able to run numerical operations on your data, as it is, because the `Sale (Dollars)` column in `df` is not formatted as a numerical type. The following piece of code will convert the data in the `Sale (Dollars)` and `Suggested answer` column to be of type float and remove the dollar sign and separating commas.

```
df[df.columns[2:]] = df[df.columns[2:]].replace('[\$,]', '', regex=True).astype(float)
```

Then, I used the following bit of code to get the cumulative value for each unique `Store Number`.

```
cum_sales_by_store_number = df.groupby('Store Number')['Sale (Dollars)'].agg(np.sum)
cum_sales_by_store_number = pd.DataFrame(cum_sales_by_store_number)
```

Output for `cum_sales_by_store_number`:

```
              Sale (Dollars)
Store Number
2106               176849.97
```

I hope this answers your question. Happy coding!